# Django Summernote not showing up in Linode Server

Tags: django, wysiwyg, summernote

I've added Django summernote to my post model and it's working perfectly in localhost. However, the summernote field is not showing up in the server. I am using DJango+Gunicorn+Nginx in Linode.

settings.py

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'  # Show summernote with Bootstrap4
```

urls.py

```
path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
```

admin.py

```
class BlogAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):  # instead of ModelAdmin
     summernote_fields = ('content','blog_post',)

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

I am quite not sure what am I doing wrong?
[Localhost summernote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYwBk.png)
[admin summernote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Zsu.png)

This is how my nginx file looks like.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pinkgiraffemarketing.com www.pinkgiraffemarketing.com; # such as: 121.21.21.65 dev.mywebsite.com

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pinkgiraffemarketing/staticfiles/;

    }

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pinkgiraffemarketing/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;

    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/pinkgiraffemarketing/staticfiles/images/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I tried all the possible solution on the internet and none worked so far.

Comment: anybody facing similar issue. Please don't forget to restart your gunicorn